# Using protected $relations in User model?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have two tables: `Users, Workers`.

The relationship is: `Users.id = Workers.user_id`

In `User model` I set related model as:

```
protected $relations = ['workers'];
```

And there is method `workers` in User model:

```
public function workers()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Workers', "user_id");
    }
```

So, in conclusion when I catch the object:

```
dd(Auth::user());
```

I dont have here attributes from related model `workers`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `workers()` relation to get this info:

```
dd(Auth::user()->workers());
```